# Регулярное выражение для выбора строки из множества одинаковых строк (Строка без префикса)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пусть есть массив входных строк:

`s = ["NT LANMAN", "LANMAN", "DOS LANMAN", PC NETWORK PROGRAM""]`

Необходимо выбрать при помощи регулярного выражения все строки, Содержащие слово `"LANMAN"`, но не содержащие словосочетание `"NT LANMAN"`

Я уже попробовал:

`(?!NT\s*)LANMAN` - не подходит.

`[^Nn][^Tt]\s*LANMAN` - тоже.

`(?!NT\s*LANMAN\s*)LANMAN` - тоже.

Протестить можно тут: https://regex101.com/r/B5zf9O/1

Программа для проверки тут: https://wandbox.org/permlink/gwi7TwRtMVEiRmFV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```cpp
check_match(R"(^(?!.*\bNT LANMAN\b).*\blanman\b)", s, n);
```

*Подробности*:

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?!.*\bNT LANMAN\b)` - сразу после начала строки не должно быть ноль и более символов, отличных от перевода строки, как можно больше, а потом целого слова `NT LANMAN`
- `.*` - ноль и более символов, отличных от перевода строки, как можно больше
- `\blanman\b` - целое слово `lanman`

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/3qQ2CL/1).

Пример кода:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

std::string s[] = {
    "PC NETWORK PROGRAM 1.0",
    "NT LM 0.12", 
    "NT LANMAN",
    "LANMAN",
    "LM",
    "DOS LANMAN"
};

void check_match(const std::string& r, const std::string* s, size_t n)
{
    std::regex re(r, std::regex_constants::icase);
    std::smatch m;
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        bool res = std::regex_search(s[i], m, re);
        cout << "  regex: '" << r << "' is " 
             << (res ? " match" : "not match")
             << ", string: '" << s[i] << "' "
             << ", m: '" << (res ? m[0].str() : "" ) << "'" << endl;
    }
    
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    size_t n = sizeof(s) / sizeof(std::string);
    check_match(R"(^(?!.*\bNT LANMAN\b).*\blanman\b)", s, n);
}
```

Результат:

```cpp
regex: '^(?!.*\bNT LANMAN\b).*\blanman\b' is not match, string: 'PC NETWORK PROGRAM 1.0' , m: ''
regex: '^(?!.*\bNT LANMAN\b).*\blanman\b' is not match, string: 'NT LM 0.12' , m: ''
regex: '^(?!.*\bNT LANMAN\b).*\blanman\b' is not match, string: 'NT LANMAN' , m: ''
regex: '^(?!.*\bNT LANMAN\b).*\blanman\b' is  match, string: 'LANMAN' , m: 'LANMAN'
regex: '^(?!.*\bNT LANMAN\b).*\blanman\b' is not match, string: 'LM' , m: ''
regex: '^(?!.*\bNT LANMAN\b).*\blanman\b' is  match, string: 'DOS LANMAN' , m: 'DOS LANMAN'
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте этот вариант - `/(?<!NT\s)LANMAN/x`

Comment: Он подходит, но только не для моего движка регулярных выражений (std::regex C++ 17)

Comment: +1 за подсказку, но для C++ это не подойдет.

Comment: И не только для C++)) Как оказалось

Comment: Да, скорее всего это новая фича ECMA regex, которая не везде есть.